# Using DB Function (TRIM(LEADING '0' from column)) in Slick

Tags: sql, scala, slick, slick-3.0

I would like to translate an SQL query into a `TableQuery`:

`SELECT ..., TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM mycolumn) FROM mytable WHERE TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM mycolumn) = '$key`

Should become `MyTableQuery.filter(<_.mycolumn something something> )`

I cannot use an `implicit MappedColumnType` because I am mapping from `String` to `String` and have other `String` columns in the result. And I have no idea how I would use it in both `SELECT` and `WHERE`

For the `SELECT` part, I have created a custom function for mapping the result tuples to my case class, so I only need a solution for the `WHERE` part.

Have read the [Coming from SQL](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.1/sql-to-slick.html) and [User defined features](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.1/userdefined.html) from the docs but unfortunately, I am none the wiser. I suppose I could use a `SimpleFunction.unary[String, String]` but have not figured out how.

I would trim a regular `String` with `dropLeft`, however `Rep[String]` does not have such a method. `ltrim` does not accept a parameter. `endsWith` is ambiguous in my case.

I cannot pad my query `String`, since not all values in the DB are padded and have different lengths.

I definitely can use plain SQL and map the results, but I would really like to understand what I am missing here.

I am using Slick 3.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slightly odd syntax of TRIM(LEADING means you have to drop to using a SimpleExpression and use the QueryBuilder that gives you access to.

```
val trimLeading = SimpleExpression.binary[String, String, String] {
  (trimChar, str, queryBuilder) =>
    import slick.util.MacroSupport._
    import queryBuilder._
    b"TRIM(LEADING $trimChar FROM $str)"
}
```

and here is an example that exercises it

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import slick.backend.DatabaseConfig
import slick.driver.JdbcProfile
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.Await

object TrimLeading extends App {
  def trimLeadingExample(dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]): Unit = {
    import dbConfig.driver.api._
    val trimLeading = SimpleExpression.binary[String, String, String] {
      (trimChar, str, queryBuilder) =>
        import slick.util.MacroSupport._
        import queryBuilder._
        b"TRIM(LEADING $trimChar FROM $str)"
    }

    class ZeroTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[String](tag, "ZeroTable") {
      def zeros = column[String]("zeros")
      def * = zeros
    }
    val zeroTable = TableQuery[ZeroTable]
    exec(zeroTable.schema.create)
    exec(zeroTable ++= Seq("000000x", "00x", "000000000x", "00000x", "00xx"))

    exec(zeroTable.
          filter(s => trimLeading("0", s.zeros) === "x").
          map(s => trimLeading("0", s.zeros)).result).foreach(println)
    exec(zeroTable.schema.drop)
    def exec[T](action: DBIO[T]): T = Await.result(dbConfig.db.run(action), Duration.Inf)
  }
  val configStr =
    """
      |  driver = "freeslick.OracleProfile$"
      |  db {
      |    driver = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
      |    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:49161/xe"
      |    properties = {
      |      databaseName = "freeslicktest"
      |      user = "system"
      |      password = "oracle"
      |    }
      |  }
    """.stripMargin
  trimLeadingExample(DatabaseConfig.forConfig[JdbcProfile]("", ConfigFactory.parseString(configStr)))
}
```

and from the logs, the statement is

`*** (s.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement) Preparing statement: select TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM "zeros") from "ZeroTable" where TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM "zeros") = 'x'`

Comment: Wow, thank you Sue C, this is working great! In the where clause at least, where I really need it. Using the `SimpleExpression` in the select clause (`map`) only works fine as long as I am fine with returning tuples. Perhaps you could take a look at [the follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253413)? Not a big issue, just being curious.